# How do I create turns in a Tic Tac Toe game?

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if this is really obvious. I am pretty new to JavaScript. I have had to create a basic X game . Here is the HTML code.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell1"></td>
            <td id="cell2"></td>
            <td id="cell3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell4"></td>
            <td id="cell5"></td>
            <td id="cell6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell7"></td>
            <td id="cell8"></td>
            <td id="cell9"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I had to write a code so that clicking on any cell, would make an X appear on the cell.

```
function click() {
    if (this.id == "cell1") {
        document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = "X";
    } else if (this.id == "cell2") {
        document.getElementById("cell2").innerHTML = "X";
    } else if (this.id == "cell3") {
        document.getElementById("cell3").innerHTML = "X";

    } else if (this.id == "cell4") {
        document.getElementById("cell4").innerHTML = "X";
    } else if (this.id == "cell5") {
        document.getElementById("cell5").innerHTML = "X";
    } else if (this.id == "cell6") {
        document.getElementById("cell6").innerHTML = "X";

    } else if (this.id == "cell7") {
        document.getElementById("cell7").innerHTML = "X";
    } else if (this.id == "cell8") {
        document.getElementById("cell8").innerHTML = "X";
    } else if (this.id == "cell9") {
        document.getElementById("cell9").innerHTML = "X";

    }
}

document.getElementById("cell1").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell2").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell3").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell4").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell5").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell6").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell7").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell8").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("cell9").onclick = click;
```

This method successfully creates an X into each and every cell on the table when clicked. The next task is something I don't understand as I have to now incorporate 'O's into the table, like a Tic Tac Toe Game..which is fine but there should be turns like once there is an X the next one should be an O and then an X and so on. Can anyone tell me please what would be appropriate to do and which method/function can be used in such an instance? Ta!

Comment: You need to create a class which will track the game state, if you're not sure what those are, then google a tic-tac-toe tutorial.

Comment: [Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: [See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MjE8V/): You don't need to check the `id` every time. `this` refers to the very object that is clicked. You should also check if the cell is filled so that it would not be overwritten by another player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a variable for it

```
 var nextTurn = 'X'
```

at the top

then something like:

```
 if (this.id == "cell1")
 {
      if(document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML == ""){ 
           document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML = nextTurn;
           changeTurn();
      }
 }
```

etc

```
 function changeTurn(){
      if(nextTurn == 'X'){
           nextTurn = 'O';
      } else {
           nextTurn = 'X';
      }
 }
```

Comment: Also, could you tell me if possible how to add a function into this code that would prevent overwriting the existing X or O's? Thank you!

Comment: @user221510 updated the answer. You will need to check the current contents of the cell to see if it has a value, if it doesn't then you update it.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up your code a bit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
td{width:20px;height:20px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
//IE 8 and below doesn't have String.trim() so have to add it
if(!String.prototype.trim){
    String.prototype.trim=function(){
        return this.replace(/^[\s]*[\s]*$/igm,"");
    }
}
var game={
    currentPlayer:"X",
     move:function(e){
        e=window.event||e;//IE uses window.event
        var src=e.target||e.srcElement;
        if(src.tagName==="TD"&&src.innerHTML.trim()===""){
            src.innerHTML=game.currentPlayer;
            game.currentPlayer=(game.currentPlayer==="X")?"O":"X";
        }
    }
}

var table=document.body.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
if(typeof table.addEventListener==="function"){
    table.addEventListener("click",game.move);
}else if(typeof table.attachEvent){
    //for IE
    table.attachEvent("onclick", game.move);
}
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```