# Stop overwriting in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, html

This is in regards to [How do I create turns in a Tic Tac Toe game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410526/how-do-i-create-turns-in-a-tic-tac-toe-game) 
I wanted to add the option that a box should not be overwritten once clicked. I used the code below and have gone through it and through material online several times but can't seem to figure out the answer. It's now suddenly making all boxes X instead of X and then O and then X. Unfortunately, I am working on a web based editor  which doesn't support Jquery and I can't edit the HTML either.

```
   var turn = "X";

  function next() 
{
  turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
  }

  function play() {
  if (this.innerHTML === "") 
  {
   this.innerHTML == turn;
   next();}
 } 



   function click()
    {

     if (this.id == "cell1")
    {
       document.getElementById("cell1").innerHTML= turn;
       play();
    }  

     else if (this.id == "cell2")
    {
      document.getElementById("cell2").innerHTML = turn;
      play();
    }

    else  if (this.id == "cell3")
    {
      document.getElementById("cell3").innerHTML = turn;
      play();
    }

    else  if (this.id == "cell4")
    {
      document.getElementById("cell4").innerHTML = turn;
      play();
    }

    else if (this.id == "cell5")
    {
      document.getElementById("cell5").innerHTML = turn;
      play();
    }

     else if (this.id == "cell6")
     {
       document.getElementById("cell6").innerHTML = turn;
       play();
      }

      else if (this.id == "cell7")
      {
        document.getElementById("cell7").innerHTML = turn;
        play(); 
      }

       else if (this.id == "cell8")
      {
        document.getElementById("cell8").innerHTML = turn;
        play();
       }

       else if (this.id == "cell9")
       {
         document.getElementById("cell9").innerHTML =turn;
         play(); 
       }

   }

     document.getElementById("cell1").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell2").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell3").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell4").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell5").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell6").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell7").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell8").onclick = click;
     document.getElementById("cell9").onclick = click;
```

I know I have been told not to repeat code but I am fairly new at this. Maybe a few months of practice will make me confident enough - I just find it clearer like this right now.

P.S: It was working fine before I tried to add the function of stopping overwriting of cells. The code before that was:

```
  var nextTurn = 'X';
  function changeTurn(){
  if(nextTurn == 'X'){
       nextTurn = 'O';
  } else {
       nextTurn = 'X';
  }     
 }
```

for the new option I have changed nextTurn to turn and changeTurn to next - with help from another user from the earlier post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant for `this.innerHTML == turn;` to be `this.innerHTML = turn;`

The first form is a comparison whereas the second is an assignment

Comment: Hi @Orangepill .. I have changed the statement to an assignment but it still gives me just X'es when I run the code. Would you know why? I am out of ideas since the code makes sense to me, but I am new to it anyway hence, asking for expert opinion. Thank you!

Comment: I think @Garath pegged this one. If your still having problems after that you might want to try changing the === to a == in the if statement in the play function. I'm not sure if an empty elements innerHTML property is null or "" but with the double equal it won't matter which.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function `play` because you already set innerHtml so if statement will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something inside the cell that is making your comparison to an empty string return false. You also have double equals in your assignment which should be a single equals.

Change the play function to be like this:

```
  function play() {
    if (!/[XO]/.test(this.innerHTML)) 
      {
        this.innerHTML = turn;
        next();
      }
  }
```

As mentioned in my comment, here is a way that I would suggest for you to do the entire program in a very short amount of code:

First of all, in your cells, put this event handler:

```
onclick="playNew(this)"
```

And create the playNew function like this:

```
function playNew(cell) {
if (!/[XO]/.test(cell.innerHTML))
cell.innerHTML = (self.turn = (self.turn == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'));
}
```

Here is a complete example (you'll probably want to improve my HTML; I just did divs and made them display as table cells and put hyphens in them to prevent them from being invisible as they would be if I put no content in them).

```
<script>

function playNew(cell) {
if (!/[XO]/.test(cell.innerHTML))
cell.innerHTML = (self.turn = (self.turn == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'));
} 
</script>

<style>
.cell { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: solid; display: table-cell }
</style>


<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div>
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div>
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div><br />
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div>
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div>
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div><br />
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div>
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div>
<div onclick="playNew(this)" class="cell">-</div><br />
```

Also, my code is just for switching between X's and O's and it does not announce a winner or keep track of positions of cells, or the end of the game, etc. I assume that your cells each have different IDs and that you have separate logic for figuring out when the game is over and whether X or O wins.

Comment: Hi Joseph Thanks for your help. I changed the play function to the above but instead now, all the cells go 'O' expect the first one, which is still 'X' but upon clicking on it, it also becomes 'O' - Do you think there might be another problem with the code? I have also tried changing just the innerHTML statement as mentioned by others but that just gives me X's.

Comment: Sure, I can actually suggest a function that would do the entire thing in a compact way. Let me add that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind assistance but the code doesnt work unfortunately on the web editor I have to use and I can;t change the HTML at all.

Comment: I don't understand why my code is only displaying X's or the one you suggested only shows O's - I'll have another look. Thanks though